# React: Render and link toggle button outside the class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following example where the `toggleComponent.js` is working perfectly.

The problem here is that I don't want to render the `<ContentComponent/>` inside the toggle, rather **I want the opposite**, I want to toggle the `<ContentComponent/>` that will be called in another component depending on the state of the toggle.

So the `<ContentComponent/>` is outside the `toggleComponent.js`, but they are linked together. So I can display it externally using the toggle.

An image to give you an idea:

[image]

Link to funtional code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fwn3rn?file=src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ToggleComponent from "./toggleComponent";
import ContentComponent from "./content";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ToggleComponent
          render={({ isShowBody, checkbox }) => (
            <div>
              {isShowBody && <h1>test</h1>}
              <button onClick={checkbox}>Show</button>
            </div>
          )}
        />

        <ToggleComponent
          render={({ isShowBody, checkbox }) => (
            <div>
              {isShowBody && (
                <h1>
                  <ContentComponent />
                </h1>
              )}
              <button onClick={checkbox}>Show</button>
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit tweaked your source.

Modified **ToggleComponent**

```
import React from "react";

export default class ToggleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checked: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    this.props.toggled(!this.state.checked);
  };

  checkbox = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Toggle</label>
        <span className="switch switch-sm">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="select" onClick={this.handleClick} />
            <span />
          </label>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return this.checkbox();
  }
}
```

Added **OtherComponent** with **ContentComponent** inside.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ContentComponent from "./content";

export default class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.show ? <ContentComponent /> : null}</div>;
  }
}
```

**Separated as per your requirement.**

Modified **App**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
import ToggleComponent from "./toggleComponent";
import OtherComponent from "./otherComponent";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.toggled = this.toggled.bind(this);
    this.state = { show: false };
  }

  toggled(value) {
    this.setState({ show: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ToggleComponent toggled={this.toggled} />
        <OtherComponent show={this.state.show} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bcsf2z?file=src/toggleComponent.js).

Comment: Perfect! Although I managed to get it to work in another method, yours is very simple and clean and I actually liked how you separated the toggle and the content, as well as including the condition to show inside the content itself. Thank you very much, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share states across components a good way to do that is to use callbacks and states. I will use below some functional components but the same principle can be applied with class based components and their `setState` function.

You can see this example running [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pdggbk?file=src%2FApp.js), I've tried to reproduce a bit what you showed in your question.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const ToggleComponent = props => {
  const { label: labelText, checked, onClick } = props;
  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onClick={onClick} />
      {labelText}
    </label>
  );
};

const ContentComponent = props => {
  const { label, children, render: renderFromProps, onChange } = props;
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const defaultRender = () => null;
  const render = renderFromProps || children || defaultRender;

  return (
    <div>
      <ToggleComponent
        label={label}
        checked={checked}
        onClick={() => {
          setChecked(previousChecked => !previousChecked);
        }}
      />
      {render(checked)}
    </div>
  );
};

const Holder = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ContentComponent label="First">
        {checked => (
          <h1>First content ({checked ? "checked" : "unchecked"})</h1>
        )}
      </ContentComponent>
      <ContentComponent
        label="Second"
        render={checked => (checked ? <h1>Second content</h1> : null)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

PS: A good rule of thumb concerning state management is to try to avoid bi-directional state handling. For instance here in my example I don't use an internal state in `ToggleComponent` because it would require to update it if given `checked` property has changed. If you want to have this kind of shared state changes then you need to use `useEffect` on functional component.

```
const ContentComponent = props => {
  const { checked: checkedFromProps, label, children, render: renderFromProps, onChange } = props;
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(checkedFromProps || false);

  const defaultRender = () => null;
  const render = renderFromProps || children || defaultRender;
    
  // onChange callback
  useEffect(() => {
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(checked);
    }
  }, [ checked, onChange ]);

  // update from props
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(checkedFromProps);
  }, [ checkedFromProps, setChecked ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <ToggleComponent
        label={label}
        checked={checked}
        onClick={() => {
          setChecked(previousChecked => !previousChecked);
        }}
      />
      {render(checked)}
    </div>
  );
};

const Other = () => {
  const [ checked, setChecked ] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div>
      { checked ? "Checked" : "Unchecked" }
      <ContentComponent checked={checked} onChange={setChecked} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes I needed to pass states between components and not the whole component indeed. I was wondering if could I pass   `this.state = {isShowBody: false,}; ` as  `{this.props.isShowBody}` and use it in something like `{ {this.props.isShowBody} && <h1>test</h1>}`. It seems to give me an error.

Comment: I don't use class-based components a lot but I think you can look for [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) which could be a bit similar to the second `useEffect` I've shown above and return `{ isShow: nextProps.isShow }`.

Concerning the first `useEffect`, the bottom-up change,maybe you should check [componentDidUpdate](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and call `this.props.onChange(nextState.isShow)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to get it working thanks to you. Anyway, as a beginner is react, could you tell me why people use functions and classes? I can't decide what to use exactly ..

Comment: For components I favor functions over classes because I find them easier to approach than classes-based ones and I rarely find cases where a class-based component is needed / better to achieve a particular goal.

What makes it easier with functions IMO, is the react's [hook system](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) (you can see some in my examples with `useState` & `useEffect`). Once you're used to it allows you to write components a bit more quickly & easily than with classes because functions are simpler and more predictable than classes.

Comment: Yes I saw that, the class system is a little bit outdated. The problem for me in the functions is that compared to classes there isn't so much tutorials for beginner. I should probably dive more into functions from the react documentation to be able to adapt more efficiently. Anyway thank you.